# Git Repo has hidden files

Tags: github

hi I am in a serious trouble my GIT repository has hidden files and I cant trace them or find them, I have a backup of everything so I removed all the files and folders in the repo(git rm -rf *)

but still when I try to fetch the size of the repo with --

`curl -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" -s https://api.github.com/repos/MissJuliaRobot/MissJuliaRobot | jq '.size' | numfmt --to=iec --from-unit=1024`

It shows 37MB but there are no files, folders nothing.

Comment: Try `ls -a` to see all files, the `.git` folder does also have a certain size, you can check it's size with `du -sh .git`

Comment: $ ls -a gives output
`.  ..  .git` also $ du -sh .git gives output `3.1M    .git`

Comment: tried removing but `rm: refusing to remove '.' or '..' directory: skipping '.'`

Comment: `.` and `..` are links to the current and parent directory, they can not be deleted. The `.git` folder contains the information about the git repository itself (all the commits, branches, etc.). Deleting it would delete the git repository and it's history. Please tell us what you want to achieve! Maybe it's the best option to delete and recreate the repository?

Comment: [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/7976758).

Comment: No there is nothing to remove then, the repository is empty (only the git history, branches etc. are taking up the space)!

Comment: my point is how can a empty repository has 37mb size even with .git folder that is only 3.1 MB in size 

Comment: if it doesn't consume any memory, then it's not a repository. it's just a folder

Comment: ok i understand and i want to know is there any way to reset everything without deleting and recreating the repo because i don't wanna use all those fork and stars

Comment: Your question appears to be about GitHub (how they store stuff and report on it) rather than about Git. I added the github tag, but perhaps you might want to remove the git tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your repository is part of a repository "network".  The way forks work, they will share objects on GitHub's servers for space savings.  Because you have 38 forks, your repository is part of that network.

Although you have rewritten your history so that *your repository* - when cloned - doesn't have those objects, your repository *network* - the way it's stored on github.com - does.

If you really want that number to say `0`, you have to not be a part of that network.  That means deleting the repository (which will make somebody else the main repository in that network.)

Comment: please have a look at this image https://telegra.ph/file/5b3779d1f5ea7d9e2cdb1.jpg

Comment: the repo is literally empty with just a readme file but still has 37.9Mb size i am using this badge `![size](https://github-size-badge.herokuapp.com/MissJuliaRobot/MissJuliaRobot.svg)`

Comment: Hmm, indeed.  I'm totally wrong.  Mea culpa, I thought this was in bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Oh well i fixed it on my own

All i need to do was create a empty branch and add the files(backed up already) and force push them in the empty branch

```
 git checkout --orphan stable
 git rm -rf .
 git commit --allow-empty -m .
 git push origin stable
 now here i added my files...
 git add .
 git commit -m "fixed"
 git switch stable
 git push -f origin stable
```

**DONE**